# issues with Django Passing Data from Template to View url dispatch

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

Having the below error while trying to dispatch two variables from my template to my view via url dispatching. I dont understand why the url is not able to be found. This is a snippet of my entire code, but I am pretty sure that the issue lies in the below. This is within an application within my project

```
NoReverseMatch at /home/patientid=1002411102/clinicid=1007/
Reverse for 'patient_summary' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['home/patientid=(?P<patient_id>\\d+)/clinicid=(?P<clinic_id>\\d+)/$']
```

**index.html**

```
<tbody>
    {% for patient in patients %}
    <tr class="gradeX">
        <td>{{patient.PatientID}}</td>
        <td>{{patient.ClinicID}}</td>
        <td>{{patient.PatientFirstName}}</td>
        <td>{{patient.PatientMidName}}</td>
        <td>{{patient.PatientLastName}}</td>
        <td>{{patient.PatientDOB}}</td>
        <td>40/30</td>
        <td>192</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>70</td>
        <td>23m</td>
        <td style="color:red">Abnormal</td>
        <td><a style="color:#4A90E2; cursor: pointer" href="{% url 'home:patient_summary' patient_id=patient.PatientID clinic_id=patient.ClinicID %}">View/Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from home import views

app_name = 'home'

urlpatterns = [
    url('^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url('patientid=(?P<patient_id>\d+)/clinicid=(?P<clinic_id>\d+)/$', views.patient_summary, name='patient_summary'),
    ]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.context_processors import request
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
import requests
import json

@login_required
    def index(request):
        payload = {"ClinicId":"1007"}
        r = requests.post("https://hidden", data=payload)
        jsonList = r.text
        data = json.loads(jsonList)
        # print(data[0]["PatientID"])
        patients = []
        for patient in data:
             patients.append(patient)
        my_dict = {'patients': patients, 'homeIsActive': 'active'}
        return render(request, 'home/index.html', my_dict)

    def patient_summary(request, patient_id, clinic_id):
        my_dict = {'homeIsActive': 'active', 'chartData': [[0,1],[1,1],[2,1]]}
        return render(request, 'home/patient_summary.html', my_dict)
```

**urls.py for base project**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.conf.urls import url
from login import views as login
from home import views as home
from enrollment import views as enrollment
from inventory import views as inventory

urlpatterns = [
    url('^$', login.user_login, name='login'),
    url('^logout/', login.user_logout, name='logout'),
    url('^home/', include('home.urls')),
    url('^enrollment/', enrollment.index, name ='enrollment'),
    url('^inventory/', inventory.index, name ='inventory'),
    # url('^settings/', settings.index, name='settings'),
    url('^settings/', include('settings.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),    
]
```

Comment: The error doesn't match your code; please post the actual template and view, as well as the index view. Also, that really isn't how you define URLs in Django.

Comment: i posted only the relevant snippets. If I copied everything, the post will be too long. I included the index view. I didnt use paths but the code works fine except for the error posted. how should urls be declard

Comment: I didn't ask for "everything", I asked for the actual code that demonstrated the problem; this clearly isn't it. Even if the patient id and clinic ID were blank for some reason the error would say that, rather than saying that you passed no arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling the url name of patient_summary from another location so thats why I kept getting the error. i think rule of thumb is always use relative url paths